# hector_quadrotor not responding to cmd_vel

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using the `hector_quadrotor` package, and tyring to simulate in gazebo.  The simulated bot does not respond to commands over `cmd_vel`, from command line (`rostopic pub`), from a custom keyboard teleop node, or even from `rosrun hector_quadrotor_controller test_trajectory`.

I'm launching gazebo and spawning the drone using

```
$ roslaunch hector_gazebo_worlds rolling_landscape_120m.launch
$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo spawn_quadrotor.launch
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but help would be appreciated!

Further tests show that `cmd_vel` does nothing with

```
$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world.launch
$ rosrun hector_quadrotor_controller test_trajectory
```

either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1096/hector_quadrotor-not-responding-to-cmd_vel/) by [David Millard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158/david-millard/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/60/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-01-29**:
There was a small bug in the `hector_gazebo_plugins` package  introduced in r811 yesterday at 18:26 MEZ, that caused nan values in the Imu message for the first simulation step, leading to the effects you described. Height control should not have been affected. Could you try again with r814, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please do not double post your questions on answers.gazebosim.org and answers.ros.org. I propose to continue on [ROS answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/53538/hector_quadrotor-not-responding-to-cmd_vel/).

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/60/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 196 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-29**:
All Gazebo questions should be on answers.gazebosim.org.